# How can I capture results of a script on a list of nodes located in the DMZ, but work with that data on the Rundeck Server?

Tags: rundeck

We have a requirement to run some scripts on target nodes located in a DMZ (read: firewall locked down except for SSH access from our intranet), and then capture the well formed results of the script and write that data to a database.  Due to DMZ restrictions, we can only access these nodes via SSH/Rundeck from our Intranet.  No other communcation is currently possible.

The question here is, how can I elevate that data outside of the node context and iteratively process that data accordingly?  (i.e. Run a script on 10 target nodes, and as a result, execute a job step outside of that node (i.e. Rundeck Server) 10 times to write the data "somewhere else".

Log Filters will allow me to capture results on the target node and create usable key/value data, but I am at an impasse on what to do next with that data to accomplish our goal.

Answer (score 0):

I did an example that works based on two jobs, the first one extract a file from node00 and store the data on data value and [pass that data](https://youtu.be/ao2SvpspWl4?t=172) as an argument using [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step) to another job which points to another node (node01).

In that way, you can pass data between jobs pointed to differents nodes (remotes or just the rundeck local server).

ExtractFileContent job (extract a file content from node00).

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>81ff0a9b-381c-4631-ab32-fbe82b649cc3</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ExtractFileContent</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node00</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>cat myfile.txt</exec>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <name>mystring</name>
              <regex>\s*([^\s]+?)\s*</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>print the value, only for debug</description>
        <exec>echo "the string value is ${data.mystring}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='UseValueOnAnotherServer' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-opt ${data.mystring}' />
          <uuid>ff5ddef9-66b9-4cb3-a5d0-8756e00e0ca4</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>81ff0a9b-381c-4631-ab32-fbe82b649cc3</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And now, UseValueOnAnotherServer which "receives" the data value from ExtractFileContent job on their option.

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>ff5ddef9-66b9-4cb3-a5d0-8756e00e0ca4</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>UseValueOnAnotherServer</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node01</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "we are at ${node.name} and the node00 value is ${option.opt}</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>ff5ddef9-66b9-4cb3-a5d0-8756e00e0ca4</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuc86.jpg) you can see the result.